# How to add custom css style in existing materialize css buttons and navbar?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, materialize

I am new to materialize css. I have made a navbar which has 4 `li` tags and one of it contains button. Now I want to change navbar background color and button size should be resized. How can I change the default color(red) of navbar and default color of button also I want to resize the button.How can it be done ?

header.js:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class Header extends Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <div>   
          <nav>
            <div class="nav-wrapper">
              <a href="#" class="brand-logo">Udacity Logo</a>
              <ul id="nav-mobile" class="right hide-on-med-and-down">
                <li><a href="#">Nanodegree</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Hire Talent</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">For Business</a></li>
                <li><a class="waves-effect waves-light btn">Course Finder</a></li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </nav>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Header;
```

What should I add in header.css ?

Screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try by adding a class to `nav` like `<nav class="yourClassName">` and set color in this css class

```
.yourClassName{
   background:colorName
}
```

Simillary add another class here

```
<li><a class="waves-effect waves-light btn customClass">Course Finder</a></li>

.customClass{
   width:xxpx
}
```

If default property does not get overwritten use `!important`

Comment: Thanks but how can I resize the button in 4th `li` tag

Comment: @stonerock `nav li:nth-child(4) {background: red;}`